# Set configuration part in startup with static parameters not json file in .net core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, dependency-injection, configuration

I have this line of code in my test solution .

I want to config ravenoption in my test code.

```
public IHost host = null;
public IDocumentStore documentStore = null;
public TestHostBuilder()
{
    ConfigureServer(new TestServerOptions() {FrameworkVersion = null});
    documentStore = GetDocumentStore();
    Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable("TEST_ENV", "on");
    var hostBuilder = easy.api.Program.CreateHostBuilder(new string[0])
.ConfigureWebHost(webHostBuilder =>
{
    webHostBuilder.UseTestServer();
}).ConfigureAppConfiguration(config =>
{
   config.Configure<domain.Environments.RavenOptions>(new domain.Environments.RavenOptions() {PublicUrl=documentStore.Urls.ToString() });


})
.ConfigureServices(services =>
{

   services.AddScoped<ICurrentUserService, InitRequest>();
   services.AddScoped<ICacheStorage>(provider =>
   {
       return new Mock<ICacheStorage>().Object;
   });
   services.AddRavenDbAsyncSession(GetDocumentStore(new GetDocumentStoreOptions()));
   services.AddTransient<IAsyncDocumentSession>((c) =>
    {
        return documentStore.OpenAsyncSession();
    });

});

    host = hostBuilder.Start();

}
```

So in this line

```
config.Configure<domain.Environments.RavenOptions>(new domain.Environments.RavenOptions() {PublicUrl=documentStore.Urls.ToString() });
```

I get this error :

> Severity   Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
> Error  CS1929  'IConfigurationBuilder' does not contain a definition for 'Configure' and the best extension method overload

Comment: Not sure what is your `RavenOptions`, any way the `Configure` extension does not exist in  `IConfigurationBuilder`. You need move it to `ConfigureServices(services =>services.Configure<RavenOptions>(.....))`. Be sure add namespace:`using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
`.

Comment: @Rena sorry for my late .public sealed record RavenOptions
    {
        public const string DefaultSectionName = nameof(RavenOptions);

        public RavenOptions()
        {
        }

        public string PublicUrl { get; set; }
        public string PublicDbName { get; set; }
        public string TseUrl { get; set; }
        public string TseDbName { get; set; }
        public string[] ShardUrls { get; set; }
        public bool IsHttps { get; set; } = true;
        public string CertificateDirectory { get; set; } = default;
    }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I created an Ioption object and inject it to the application :

```
.ConfigureServices(services =>
        {
            domain.Environments.RavenOptions appSettings = new domain.Environments.RavenOptions()
            {
                PublicDbName = documentStore.Database,
                CertificateDirectory="",
                IsHttps=false,
                PublicUrl=documentStore.Identifier.Split("(").First(),
                TseDbName=documentStore.Database,
                ShardUrls=Enumerable.Repeat(documentStore.Identifier.Split("(").First(), 4).ToArray()
            };
            IOptions<domain.Environments.RavenOptions> options = Options.Create(appSettings);
                   services.AddScoped<IOptions<domain.Environments.RavenOptions>>((p) =>
            {
                return options;
            });
```